# Vim smart insert semicolon

Tags: vim

Is there a Vim plugin that can handle smart semicolon insertion, like the one in Eclipse?

Example (pipe character is insertion cursor):

```
foobar(|)
```

I type a semicolon:

```
foobar();|
```

Similarly:

```
foobar("blah|")
```

I type a semicolon:

```
foobar("blah");|
```

If I want a semicolon at the original cursor position, I press backspace after the smart re-position:

```
foobar("hello|")
foobar("hello");|
foobar("hello;|")
```

Comment: And what if you want to actually have a semicolon inside your string literal?

Comment: In Eclipse pressing backspace after a smart semicolon insert will put the semicolon in the original cursor position.

Comment: The ideal solution: use Python. Then you don't need to worry about semicolons ;-)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan For my poor brain, switching between Python and Java/C++/JavaScript is somewhat like switching between Mac and Windows.  I can do basically the same things in the same way, but with enough devilish differences to give me a migraine.

Answer (score 32):

I use this mapping:

```
inoremap <leader>; <C-o>A;
```

It's not `;` because I use semicolons often and in more than one context.

- `<C-o>` is used to input a single normal mode command.
- `A;` means "add a `;` at the end of the line".

Comment: @dansomething: Oh yes! Since that answer, I've modified that line many times in my `~/.vimrc`. Here is the current incarnation: inoremap <leader>; <C-o>m`<C-o>A;<C-o>``

Comment: With your mapping, vim waits for a second character on each <leader> key press.

Comment: @Koshimitsu this is standard behavior and you notice it only if you pause yourself.

Comment: @TARDISMaker, I don't have that mapping anymore. Are you talking about the one in my comment? `<C-o>` leaves insert mode for a single command. m` creates a context mark. `<C-o>` again. `A;` appends a semicolon at the end of the line. `<C-o>` again. And finally `` to jump back to the mark we set earlier.

Comment: Frankly id rather use something that wont trip up insert mode, like a function key (which ill never remember) or a ctrl shortcut

Answer (score 11):

I want to do the same thing, I works on it whole night, tons of code, but at last, I got a simple solution.

```
inoremap ;<cr> <end>;<cr>
```

and if I am in a brace, I want to add a semicolon or a dot at the end, like this

```
foo({
  |
})
```

I press `;;<cr>` or `..<cr>` to do this

```
inoremap ;<cr> <end>;<cr>
inoremap .<cr> <end>.
inoremap ;;<cr> <down><end>;<cr>
inoremap ..<cr> <down><end>.
```

Answer (score 7):

You should try [Cosco.vim](https://github.com/lfilho/cosco.vim) plugin.

Comment: Thank you for this! This is really a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

For vscode vim users:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
      {
        "before": [";", ";"],
        "after": ["<Esc>","A",";"]
      },
    ],
```

I was inspired by [romainl's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187679/12521542), but `<C-o>` seems have a switch problem in vocode vim, so just use `<Esc>` will work.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following function and a mapping to insert a semicolon to the end of the line and to delete the remaning spaces:

```
imap <leader>. <C-R>=Semicolonfun()<CR>
fun! Semicolonfun() "{{{
  call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '\s*$', ';', ''))
  return "\<End>"
endfunction "}}}
```

So if you have something like:

```
log.warning("you miss the |identifier")
```

Pressing . or ,. if you remap the leader, you get the following:

```
log.warning("you miss the identifier");|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inoremap <expr> ;<cr> getline('.')[-1:] == ';' ? '\<Nop>' : '<End>;<CR>'
```

The code above will check if there is `;` at the end of the line.

If `;` not exists, then it will add `;` otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
" ftplugin/c/c_snippet.vim
inoremap <expr> <buffer> ; getline('.')[col('.')-1:-1]=~')$' ? '<right>;' : ';'
```

This version shall not pose problems with `for` if your snippets engine expands it into

```
for (...|) {
   <+code+>
}<++>
```

If the open bracket is on a newline, it will mess things up.

You could easily change the regex to `'"\=)\+$'` to answer your initial question.

```
inoremap <expr> <buffer> ; getline('.')[col('.')-1:-1]=~'"\=)\+$' ? '<end>;' : ';'
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea. In that case, the mapping for `<bs>`will be:

```
inoremap <expr> <buffer> <bs> getline('.')[:col('.')-2] =~ '.*")\+;$' ? '<bs><c-o>F";' : '<bs>'
```