# Hotkey to end the line with a semicolon and jump to a new line in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, hotkeys, sublimetext

I'm trying to figure out a hotkey at work. I just got this job and I am using a Mac for more or less the first time in my life.

Back home on my Laptop, when using Eclipse, I seem to remember there being a single hotkey which would both:

- Add a `;` to the **end** of my current line (no matter where the caret was within said line)
- Place my cursor at the beginning of a **new line**, with the same indentation level as the line I had just added a semicolon to

Does anybody know if this was an Eclipse-specific hotkey, or know of a way to replicate said hotkey in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Best solution for this is **recording a macro** on Sublime Text and then assigning it to a keyboard shortcut. Follow these steps:

1. Create a line such as alert('hello') and leave the cursor right
   after letter 'o'.
2. Then go to *Tools > Record a Macro* to start recording.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to go to the end of line.
4. Press <kbd>;</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Stop recording the macro by going to *Tools > Stop Recording Macro*
6. You can now test your macro by *Tools > Playback Macro* (optional)
7. Save your macro by going to *Tools > Save Macro* (ex: EndOfLine.sublime-macro)
8. Create a shortcut by adding this between the square brackets in your
   in your Preferences > Key Bindings - User file:

   ```
   {
   "keys": ["super+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/EndOfLine.sublime-macro"}
   }
   ```
9. Now, every time you hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, it will
   magically place the semicolon at the end of current line and move the cursor to the next line.

Happy coding!

Comment: what about in windows. instead of command. should it be ctrl?

Comment: @Vincent Instead of Command+RightArrow, you can use the End key

Comment: For windows users. To bind the macro to "ctrl+;" use the following code: `{
"keys": ["ctrl+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/EndOfLine.sublime-macro"}
}`

Comment: This won't work with Italian keyboards because semicolon is accessible with shift and comma [--->](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Italian_Keyboard_layout.svg), so the combination in this case should be `"ctrl+,"`, or something like that.

Comment: i just log in to thumb up!

Comment: Nice solution! Also a great little insight into Sublime Text Macros. Thank you!!  

Answer (score 19):

After reading your question about three times, I finally realized that you were looking for *one* hotkey to perform both operations. Whoops.

Your request sounds like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> hotkey of the [Smart Semicolon](https://code.google.com/p/smartsemicolon/) Eclipse plugin. While adding [semicolons of a genius-level IQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187477/vim-smart-insert-semicolon) would probably require an entirely new Sublime Text 2 plugin, you can easily create a smart semicolon–esque key binding with Sublime Text's [Macros](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html). I actually didn't know about them until now!

In this case, recording the macro yourself is actually the fastest way to create it, rather than copying and pasting a new file (and now you'll have the experience for making more). First, open a new file and type in your favorite garbage line:

```
Lord Vetinari's cat|
```

Then move the caret to anywhere within the line:

```
Lord Veti|nari's cat
```

Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, the hotkey for `Tools -> Record Macro`. If the status bar is enabled, it will notify you that it is "Starting to record [a] macro". Press <kbd>End</kbd> (if you don't have an <kbd>End</kbd> key, skip to below), then <kbd>;</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Finally, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> again to stop recording. When you do, the status bar will display "Stopped recording macro". Check that your macro is working by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on a code segment of your choosing.

Just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will adjust indentation on the next line accordingly as long as the `"auto_indent"` setting is set to `true`. See `Preferences -> Settings – Default`, line 59.

When you're satisfied, save your new macro with `Tools -> Save Macro...`. I saved mine as `Packages/User/smart-semicolon.sublime-macro`. My file looked something like this; feel free to copy it if you can't or won't make the macro manually:

```json
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "extend": false,
            "to": "eol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": ";"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": "\n"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    }
]
```

`"extend": false,` just means that the macro won't add any text to the working selection. Read more about the options for commands at the [Unofficial Docs Commands Page](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/commands.html).

Now that you have your macro, we can give it a custom key binding. Add the following lines to your `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User` file:

```json
 { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/smart-semicolon.sublime-macro"}, "context":
      [
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.java" }
      ]
 },
```

Replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> with whatever key binding you prefer, save your file, and give it a shot. The `"context"` array restricts the key binding to Java files (see [the Unofficial Docs Key Bindings](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) page for more information on contexts); if you want the key binding to be active everywhere, use this line instead:

```json
 { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/smart-semicolon.sublime-macro"} },
```

This [NetTuts+ article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-banish-repetitive-tasks-with-sublime-text-2-macros/) has *much* more information on macros and binding them to keys; I referenced it often. This [UserEcho post](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/90524-add-semicolon-and-newline/) looks like it has more information on making the insertion more extensible.

Comment: I'm glad you understand my request, but so far what you've listed isn't working for me.... --- is there private messaging on stackoverflow? i cant put code in these stupid comments

Comment: @SamuelStiles That's odd. SO doesn't have a messaging system, but feel free to send me an email (check my [user page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2259675/protractor-ninja)) and I'll be glad to help. I'll update the answer after we fix things.

Comment: I'll do that when I get home from work tonight - talk to you soon!

Comment: +1 for mentioning macros which is something I use way to little but that is perfect for this case.

Comment: @SamuelStiles I found a problem in the keybinding code; `equals` was supposed to be `equal`. Hopefully that will have fixed your problem.

Comment: @ProtractorNinja, excellent post. Great references. Just wanted to mention that if you show your status bar in sublime text, it will indicate when you start recording a macro.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use a ready-made sublime package built for this purpose: [AppendSemiColon](https://github.com/MauriceZ/AppendSemiColon)

You can use [package control](https://packagecontrol.io/) to install it, just search for "AppendSemiColon".

```
Place a semicolon at the end of the cursor's current line(s) by pressing:
Command+; on OS X
Ctrl+; on Windows and Linux
```

and

```
You can also automatically go to the next line at the same time like this:
Command+Shift+; on OS X
Ctrl+Shift+; on Windows and Linux
```

I've been using this package for a while now, and it works great.

UPDATE:
As the author mentioned in a comment, you can now also change the [default hotkeys](https://github.com/MauriceZ/AppendSemiColon/blob/master/Default.sublime-keymap) if you like (personally, I love the defaults). As an example, just change:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+;"], "command": "append_semi_colon" }, 
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "append_semi_colon", "args": {"enter_new_line": "true"} }
]
```

in your sublime-keymap to use whatever keys you want.

I tested the latest version, and this feature too works fine. There was a bug where extra semicolons were being appended incorrectly upon extra hotkey presses - this minor annoyance has been fixed too. Thanks, MauriceZ/mzee99!

Comment: Hey I made this! I released an update a few days ago which should allow you to bind custom hotkeys.

Comment: Its better to change the default keybindings - on ST3, ctrl+; means opening the goto anything function (#), i.e., fuzzy search in file. Also, shift + ; ends up as a : on my English keyboard, effectively rendering the second command inaccessible. Apart from that, great little helper!

Comment: Perfect, many thanks to the author, I made a custom shortcut, that's awsome!

[
   { "keys": ["super+;"], "command": "append_semi_colon", "args": {"enter_new_line": "true"} }
]

Comment: This is good one.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will create a new line with the same level of indentation.

I could not find anything like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you mentioned

Comment: You can create your own bindings with this [syntax](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Sublime Text 3 ... inspired by your post, I've added the following to my .sublime-keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/endOfLine.sublime-macro"} },
```

I'm amazed at how much time this saves.

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe covered the second point. You can mimic the behavior of the first with a simple macro or plugin. I say or because you didn't describe the cursor position after you hit the key combination. Does it move the cursor to the next line? Does it insert a new line? I think you get the idea.

I'm pretty sure eclipse works on OS X as well as windows, so if you are more comfortable with that, why not use it (unless your job requires ST of course)? Most of the key bindings are probably the same/similar (well it's probably command rather than control for shortcuts).

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx

If you continue using ST, it's probably worthwhile to learn the basics of plugins. A lot can be built so you have the same behavior as other editors, it just takes some extra effort (through creating the plugin or finding a plugin that does it) up front.