# Sublime Text binding: insert semicolon at eol and come back

Tags: macros, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I'm new to Sublime Text key bindings. Is there a way, when the caret isn't at the end of the line, to insert a semicolon at the end? In macro I guess it'd be: go to eol -> insert ; -> come back. But I'm not sure how to do the come back part.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need this particular functionality. In what situations would it be advantageous? [Adding a semicolon and then moving to a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675320/hotkey-to-end-the-line-with-a-semicolon-and-jump-to-a-new-line-in-sublime-text-2) is pretty obvious, but in this case I'm stumped.

Comment: Entering a new line is often not what I want. Lots of times I already have a new line, and it'd get counterproductive to remove another one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to use a plugin I think since you want to restore the previous position, though I could be wrong. This is an ST3 version.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SemicolonInsertCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region_name = "original_cursors"
        view = self.view
        view.add_regions(region_name, view.sel())
        view.run_command("move_to", {"extend": False, "to": "eol"})
        view.run_command("insert", {"characters": ";"})
        view.sel().clear()
        cursors = view.get_regions(region_name)
        for cursor in cursors:
            view.sel().add(sublime.Region(cursor.b, cursor.b))
        view.erase_regions(region_name)
```

Create a key binding with the command `semicolon_insert`. I assumed your macro definition was supposed to be eol not eof.

**Edit:**
ST2 compatible version

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SemicolonInsertCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region_name = "original_cursors"
        view = self.view
        view.add_regions(region_name, list(view.sel()), "")
        view.run_command("move_to", {"extend": False, "to": "eol"})
        view.run_command("insert", {"characters": ";"})
        view.sel().clear()
        cursors = view.get_regions(region_name)
        for cursor in cursors:
            view.sel().add(sublime.Region(cursor.b, cursor.b))
        view.erase_regions(region_name)
```

Comment: It gives me the error that View.add_regions(View, str, RegionSet)
did not match C++ signature:…, any help?

Comment: Sorry about that. I had written it in ST3 and forgot about some api changes with the `add_regions` method. I've put up a ST2 compatible version.

Comment: This works! I've also put a parameter for accepting any char. Good for putting commas in json files. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What If I wanted the `;` at the end of the next line? [eg. inside a function without a semicolon](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-c_KeY9GXLfw/UyDz9WCvPKI/AAAAAAAAAr0/PStZR_J41Cs/s0/2014-03-13_07-55-30.png)

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea You can do that with a macro, as described by BullfrogBlues. To record, stop and save a macro, go to the Tools menu.  Of course, that makes the assumption that you have auto indent setup as that will insert tabs to the proper location. A potential issue with macros for the original solution will come up if you are using bookmarks elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

### Record a macro, save it, and configure a shortcut for it.

#### Create the Macro

In vintage Mode

- Start recording macro <kbd>q</kbd> followed by <kbd>**MACRO_ID** ( LETTER [a-z] )</kbd>
- Create a bookmark <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Move to end of line and into insert mode <kbd>Shift+A</kbd>
- Add the semi-colon `;` and put back in command mode <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Go to bookmark <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Remove bookmark <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Stop recording macro <kbd>q</kbd>

You can replay your macro: <kbd>@</kbd> followed by <kbd>**YOUR_MACRO_ID**</kbd>

#### Save the macro

- Go to: Tools > Save Macro...
- Name it and save it e.g. `Packages/User/Macros/complete-semi-colon.sublime-macro`

#### Create a shortcut for the macro

- Open your Key Bindings config file: Preferences > Key Bindings - User
- Create a shortcut for your new macro e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> e.g.

  ```
  { 
      "keys": ["ctrl+;"], 
      "command": "run_macro_file", 
      "args": {
          "file": "Packages/User/Macros/complete-semi-colon.sublime-macro"
      } 
  }
  ```

You can do something similar without vintage mode. The important parts are the bookmark, and the macro shortcut configuration.

Enjoy.

Comment: This is awesome, I use it all the time. Do you know how to deal with the problem that arises when prepending, not appending, text to the line from macro - the bookmark position gets lost and the cursor won't get at its place before executing the macro?

Comment: @certainlyakey Check out https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-php-grammar/blob/9ca906e8bb6da40614fd222c93967f94ea423f34/Default.sublime-keymap as an example of context sensitive macros

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification to code above. Add toggle behavior. So when you again invoke key combination semicolon will be removed. This is Sublime Text 3 version.

```
class SemicolonInsertCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region_name = "original_cursors"
        view = self.view
        view.add_regions(region_name, view.sel())
        view.run_command("move_to", {"extend": False, "to": "eol"})
        pos = view.sel()[0].begin()
        last_chr = view.substr(pos-1)
        if last_chr != ';':
            view.run_command("insert", {"characters": ";"})
        else:
            view.run_command("left_delete")
        view.sel().clear()
        cursors = view.get_regions(region_name)
        for cursor in cursors:
            view.sel().add(sublime.Region(cursor.b, cursor.b))
        view.erase_regions(region_name)
```

To add keyboard shortcut insert next line to "Preferences > Key Bindings - User":

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+enter"], "command": "semicolon_insert" }
```